# REGEXP_SUBSTR - "substring out of bounds" error

Tags: pattern-matching, teradata, regexp-substr

I have

```
select col1,
( REGEXP_SUBSTR ( col2, ' ( ?<=~ ) .*? ( ?=ABCD ) ' ) 
    || SUBSTRING ( col2 FROM POSITION ( 'ABCD' IN col2 ) 
    FOR POSITION ( '~' IN SUBSTRING ( col2 FROM POSITION ( 'ABCD' IN col2 ) ) ) -1 ) as xyz) 
from db.table 
where col2 like '%ABCD%';
```

I have a field with values as decribed in below pattern.

> Name1#Value1 ~ Name2#Value2 ~ ......... ~ NameX#ValueX ~ ........... ~
>   NameN#ValueN

There is no limit for number of name&value sections. One such Name will have 'ABCD' pattern. I want to extract that section of name and value which contains the 'ABCD' pattern and put it in a separate field.

My code above throws

> "substring out of bounds"

error.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some actual data, looks like name-value-pairs? You might be able to switch to `nvp` like `Nvp(col2, 'ABCD','\ ~\ ', '#')`

Comment: fshjk#3~dhaj#NON-LOCAL~dhahdate#64030~kjqiwDATE2#64030`75:~kwokdNUM#000000010652~ncdj#158672694~pwkd#410~djakj#147~xkiww#322285781~lowqABCD#1025133646~jdoi#~pwdljae#25133648~pqeidjdt#04212016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're looking for a pattern and an exact name you can't use `NVP`, but there's no need for mixing `REGEXP_SUB` and `SUBSTRING`.

This regex [(~|^)([^~]*?ABCD.*?#.*?)(~|$)](https://regex101.com/r/qToX3X/1/) finds the 1st `~name#value~` pattern which contains `ABCD` in it's name:

```
Trim(Both '~' FROM RegExp_Substr(col2, '(~|^)([^~]*?ABCD.*?)(~|$)',1,1,'i'))
```

The `'i'` indicates a *case insensitive* search.

If your release supports the (undocumented) `RegExp_Substr_gpl` there's no need to trim because it supports returning a specific capturing group:

```
RegExp_Substr_gpl( col2, '(~|^)([^~]*?ABCD.*?#.*?)(~|$)',1,1,'i',2)
```

Comment: Awesome Dnoeth! It worked like charm. Thank you so much for your help.